# How to make some layer mask in Silverlight?

Tags: silverlight, xaml, silverlight-3.0

I have an image object and a rectangle object. Now I want to be the image to be only visible where the rectangle is, everything else should have an opacity of 0.5 - the result should look something simliar to the following:

[image: example]

When I set the opacity of the rectangle to 0.5 the effect is the antipode - so how could I realize it as shown in the image? Size and position of the rectangle is changed by code-behind, but that shouldn't make any differences...

All hints / answeres appreciated :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want to add an opaque mask to partially hide your image outside of a rectangle, it's rather easy.

```
<Grid>
  <Image Source="myImage.jpg" Opacity="0.5/>
  <Image Source="myImage.jpg" >
   <Image.Clip>
     <RectangleGeometry Rect="x,y,w,h"/>
   </Image.Clip>
  </Image>

</Grid>
```

Where x,y,w and h are your rectangle position and size (see [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/fr-fr/library/bb979959%28v=VS.95%29.aspx)).  If you want to move the visible portion around, set the Clip property by code.

If you want to add the "black stroke effect", you could simply add a Rectangle with position and size matching those of your clipping path after the second image in your grid.

Do you want more infos?